# MS Access: How to automatically populate a PK that is also a FK to another tables auto increment PK?

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access

I'm working on updating a MS Access application that is connected to a MySQL database through an ODBC connector. I'm currently stuck on an issue where I have a form thats record source is a query that joins multiple tables, the 2 tables of issue are roughly structured as shown below.

```sql
Table1 {
   id int not null auto increment,
   ...,
   primary key(id)
}

Table2 {
   table1ID int not null default 0,
   ...,
   primary key(table1ID),
   constraint `fk` foreign key (table1ID) references Table1 (id) on delete cascade on update cascade
}
```

The problem being that Table2's primary key is also a foreign key that references Table1's id and because they are joined in the same query for the record source they both get created at the same time. So when I attempted to add a new record in MS Access, it won't save the record because Table2's "table1ID" is null but Table1's "id" is auto increment so isn't created until the record is first saved. So my question is... is there a way to have MS Access/MySQL automatically fill in Table2's "table1ID" with the auto increment value from Table1's "id" so that MS access is able to save the record?

The error message that gets returned upon trying to save a new record is as follows:

```
Run-time error '3155':

ODBC--insert on a linked table 'Table2' failed.

[MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a)Driver][mysqld-8.0.27]Column 'table1ID' cannot be null (#1048)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to execute a save in the form that creates the table 1 record.

In fact, this is also why Access will execute a automatic record save in a form when you move focus to the sub form. Access does this, since the autonumber ID on a new reocrd is NOT created until you save the reocrd (at least this is the case when using a ODBC data source). With access only, the reocrd save is not required to generate the PK id, but with sql server, or MySql - you MUST save the record.

As noted, with a form + sub form, access does this automatic.

However, say I am on a form, just added a new reocrd, and now i want to run some code, or launch another form? I MUST force a reocrd save first to generate the PK autonumber.

So, code will look like this:

```
if me.dirty then me.Dirty = false   ' save reocrd
' now do your other business here, code that follows, or 
' even launch another form, or whatever.
```

So, a simple force of form record save with me.Dirty = false will force the autonumber generation.

I don't know how MySQL works with a join between two tables, but as a general rule only ONE of the two tables in the join can be updated at a given time.

Thus, you have to break out the steps here, or not allow both tables to be edited (or at least dirty at the same time).

Access does and did allow both tables to become dirty, but server side systems to my knowledge do not. So, you could while editing on the form, when  you tab out of a control that is based on the one record, you would execute a me.Dirty = false to generate the auto PK.

However, I don't recommend allowing editing of a form that is based on more then one table at a given time - most server systems don't allow this.

So, add, and save that first record before any child record is attempted to be added here.

Comment: Currently Table1 and Table2 are on the same form. I'll try move Table2 into a subform and see how that goes. So at least Table1 can be saved separately to Table2. Thanks

Comment: Yes, we dont' save table 1 to table 2. We save, tuck away, and 100% ensure that the parent record is saved. The you are free to deal with child or related reocrds. As I pointed out, this is simply a limiation of the relational database model. I doubt that MySQL allows direct edit of a query that involves two tables. and if it does, as I stated only one table can get dirty at a given time. Think of ACID, and think of table triggers (before update) and a huge long list of issues that arise from allows one row with two data sources to be saved in one shot - it actually not really possible.